# POP3 GetMessages with UIDS

Tags: vb.net, mailkit

I use MailKit version 1.18.1.1 and I would like to switch to the latest version but I can't because GetMessages no longer accepts a list of UIDS but wants a list of int32. Why? Is there no possibility to use the old version of GetMessages again? My mail client uses to compare the list of UIDS in the database with the one read on the POP server to define which UIDS to download. Thank you for any replies and suggestions

Comment: [Pop3Client.GetMessageUids](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Pop3_Pop3Client_GetMessageUids.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the APIs that accepted UIDs because it required MailKit to keep its own copy of a UID-to-index mapping which not only meant more memory usage but it was also more complicated to keep in sync with the server.

What you need to do now is to call client.GetMessageUids() to get your own list of UIDs and then figure out which indexes you want based on that UID list.

```
var uids = client.GetMessageUids ();
var indexes = new List<int> ();

for (int i = 0; i < uids.Length, i++) {
    if (!HaveSeen (uids[i]))
        indexes.Add (i);
}

// now you have a list of indexes that you want
```